# What "extra protection" from ammonia is needed during an EVA?

Tags: iss, eva

From a Scientific American [article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/international-space-station-suffers-leak-but-crew-remains-safe/#:%7E:text=Toxic%20ammonia%20flakes%20were%20observed,%22possible%22%20leak%20on%20camera)$^\color{magenta}{\star}$ on an ammonia leak at the ISS:

> Ammonia is so toxic that spacewalks nearby the substance must have extra precautions built in to reduce exposure risk to astronauts

What are these “extra precautions”? I can’t imagine how an EVA suit could be improved upon for protection during the EVA. Are they referring to the other ISS staff being exposed after the EVA astronaut has cleared the airlock?

> For now, NASA has asked its Expedition 70 ISS astronauts to close all shutters on the U.S. segment of the space station "as a precaution against contamination," agency officials wrote.

What "shutters" are these?

---

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\star}$ Elizabeth Howell, [International Space Station suffers leak, but crew remains safe](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/international-space-station-suffers-leak-but-crew-remains-safe), Space.com, October 11, 2023.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"***extra precautions***" = visual inspections and bakeout time.

> The entire “Wet QD” ops was timelined in order to allow enough time
> for a “bake out” prior to ingress, should the EMUs become contaminated
> with any leaking ammonia from the QDs.

- EMU = Extravehicular Mobility Unit aka spacesuit
- QD = Quick Disconnect

From https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2012/11/astronaut-duo-spacewalk-iss-isolate-ammonia-leak/

Another example

> We know there is ammonia in the area... so they will do a visual
> inspection of each other to make sure there is no ammonia ice on their
> suits. Once they have concluded that they are clean, that starts a
> bake out timer. We do that to make sure we have adequate time for any
> hidden ammonia that might be on the suits to evaporate. On a rough
> order of magnitude, 30 to 45 minutes is required for that bake out
> time.
>
> That clock starts and they will begin their transit back to the
> airlock, down the P6 truss. Once they get in the airlock, they will
> hook up on umbilicals, they will repress the airlock to 5 psi and
> perform a test... a simple way of detecting of how much ammonia might
> be in the atmosphere at that 5 psi level. And based on that we'll make
> a determination if there is contamination or not. If consumables
> permit, they may do a second test. We don't anticipate that to be
> required.

ISS Flight Director Norm Knight quoted here http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum30/HTML/001202.html

***"What "shutters" are these?"***

The ISS windows (at least on the US side) have external shutters most easily seen on the cupola.

[image]

From [https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss023e042367/iss023e042367~orig.jpg](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss023e042367/iss023e042367%7Eorig.jpg), hand-drawn circles mine.

This image from STS-130 shows all the cupola shutters closed

[image]

(Image: NASA)

Comment: Thanks. I had pictured "shutters" as being Venetian Blinds. Is the "bake-out time" done after pressurizing the airlock?

Comment: So the "extra protection" is AFTER, not DURING the EVA?

Comment: @Woody Inspection & bakeout is prior to airlock ingress. They can be moving during bakeout. Added more of the FD quote.

Comment: Why close shutters? How does this benefit crew inside a pressure hull?

Comment: @Woody No snowflakes on the windows, please. Note the article says "as a protection against contamination" They are protective of the windows, especially the WORF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_Observational_Research_Facility

Comment: FWIW, ammonia can be neutralised (kind of) by reacting it with chlorine, producing [ammonium chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_chloride). But I suppose chlorine-based bleach isn't popular on the ISS...

Comment: @PM 2Ring: No! That will produce a very explosive (and a ***very*** unstable explosive at that) compound (similar to [iodine + ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_triiodide)): *[Nitrogen trichloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_trichloride#Safety)* (*"The pure substance is a dangerous explosive, being sensitive to light, heat, even moderate shock, and organic compounds."*). I think you mean [hydrochloric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid) (HCl). But any sufficiently strong acid will do, incl. relative weak acids.

Comment: cont' - The same for [bromide + ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_tribromide). Never mix ammonia with [halogens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogens) (except in very small quantities).

Comment: @PeterMortensen It depends. If there's an excess of ammonia, the reaction tends to produce ammonium chloride, but if there's an excess of chlorine it tends to produce nitrogen trichloride. Chloramine may also be produced. FWIW, one of my friends in high school made nitrogen triiodide in his home lab. He didn't attempt to bring it to school. ;)

Comment: @Woody There are many shutter constraint requirements for USOS windows to prevent contamination. Offgassing from visiting vehicles and recently flown payloads, thruster firings, and purges all require the Cupola windows and WORF to be shuttered. The Increment Lead OC is responsible for maintaining a spreadsheet with the amount of time WORF is open during various contamination "rate" scenarios - like how many visiting vehicles and where they're docked/berthed. If the area under the curve reaches a certain limit for a calendar year, the shutter must remain closed for the remainder of the year.